# Menu items color not changing when hovering

Tags: html, css, menu

So I've made a code which looks something like this :- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rpAGv

The problem is when you hover on the menu item it doesn't change the color. However, if you hover a bit lower it shows the change in color. How can i fix this? I know its something to do with the z-index but i cant figure out what.

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,700);
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-opener, .menu-opener:hover, .menu-opener.active, .menu-opener-inner, .menu-opener-inner::before, .menu-opener-inner::after, .menu, .menu.active {
  -webkit-transition: 250ms all;
  transition: 250ms all;
}

.menu-opener {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  right: 1%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 64px;
}
.menu-opener:hover, .menu-opener.active {
  background: #231F20;
}

.menu-opener-inner {
  background: #000;
  height: .5rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
  margin-top: 1.75rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
}
.menu-opener-inner::before, .menu-opener-inner::after {
  background: #000;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: .5rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
}

.menu-opener-inner::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
  transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
}
.menu-opener-inner::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.25rem);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0.25rem);
  transform: translateY(0.25rem);
}
.menu-opener-inner.active {
  background: transparent;
}
.menu-opener-inner.active::before {
    background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu-opener-inner.active::after {
    background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu {
  background: #231F20;
  color: transparent;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
 right: 1%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 0rem;
  z-index: -1;
}
.menu.active {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 2rem);
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  height: calc(100% - 1rem);
}
.menu.active .menu-link {
  color: white;
}

.menu-inner {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 4rem;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-link {
  color: transparent;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-link li {
  margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu {
    height: auto;
  }
  .menu-inner {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-link {
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .menu.active {
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 0.5rem);
    width: calc(100% - 0.5rem);
  }
}

p {
    letter-spacing:2px;
    -webkit-animation: myanim 1s;
          animation: myanim 1s;
}

span {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-animation: center 1s;
    animation: center 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes center {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.1); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: scaleX(1); }
}
@keyframes center {
  0%   { transform: scaleX(0.1); }
  100% { transform: scaleX(0.1); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes myanim {
  0%   { letter-spacing: -2px; }
  100% { letter-spacing:2px; }
}
@keyframes myanim {
  0%   { letter-spacing: -2px; }
  100% { letter-spacing:2px; }
}
```

Comment: do you want to change the text color on hover? then use:
`.menu-link:hover {
  color:red !important;
}`
in your fiddle, nothing is changing.

Comment: I'm sorry I put the wrong link by mistake. Please check now. The colors changing but only when the mouse is below the menu items and not on it

Comment: That fiddle works fine? :S

Comment: It doesnt work when i hover it on the menu link. It works when i hover below the menu links

Comment: That's really odd. I would expect it to be an issue with just your device? Have you tried the code in different browsers? On a different device? Check here, I've literally copy and pasted your exact code into Jsfiddle. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/benjih111/erojfL33/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the menuopener to have a `z-index` of 2, and changed the menu class to have a `z-index` of 1. Then added the `.menu-link:hover{ background: pink !important;}` See my fiddle below :)

http://jsfiddle.net/benjih111/wz28k13w/

Comment: If I put an image in the body..say for example the logo. Is it possible to bring it in front using the z-index?

Comment: Behind the menu when it's open? Or on the menu?

Comment: If you put the logo in a div, then assign that div a `z-index` of 2, for on top of the menu, it will show when the menu is open. :)

Comment: Throw `position: relative;` into the inline style :)

Comment: Where you have put the `z-index: 2;` where the logo is, change it to `z-index: 2; position: relative;` :)

Comment: You've just spelt position wrong! :) You've missed out the i. Also, I would keep the z-index as 2, otherwise it will overlap the menu button. :)